# Does the BlockingCollection.AddToAny Method offer any performance advantages over adding to a single BlockingCollection?

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety, blockingcollection

As far as I know, adding to a BlockingCollection doesn't block, o AddToAny that I can think of, is if some of them called CompleteAdding().
Is this the only use for AddToAny? And once they all call CompleteAdding, AddToAny will always fail for this list of BlockingCollection objects?

Comment: [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0): "Provides blocking and ***bounding*** capabilities". What do you think happens if one or more of the collections is currently full?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an item in a `BlockingCollection` can block in case the collection is bounded, and its internal buffer is currently full. That's why the [`TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.tryadd) method exists, which never blocks, and instead returns `false` in that case (without adding the item). The [`AddToAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.addtoany) method attempts initially to find a collection that is unbounded, and calls `TryAdd` to that collection. [Source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system/sys/system/collections/concurrent/BlockingCollection.cs.html#1a2116d7bc90bad7):

```
/// <summary>
/// Fast path for TryAddToAny to find a non bounded collection and add the items in it
/// </summary>
private static int TryAddToAnyFast(BlockingCollection<T>[] collections, T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < collections.Length; i++)
    {
        if (collections[i].m_freeNodes == null)
        {
            collections[i].TryAdd(item);
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Consequently using the `AddToAny` with a single unbounded collection will result to more work and increased overhead, so it cannot be faster than calling `Add` (or `TryAdd`) to that collection directly.